# copy the values of an array to the rows of a dataframe

Tags: pandas, numpy

I have an array , a= [5,25,15], and a data frame:

| volume | price | loc |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 20 | 16 |
| 3 | 50 | 14 |
| NaN | NaN | NaN |
| 10 | 40 | 13 |

I want to replace the third row of my df with a.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `loc` for set values, but need match length of list by length of columns:

```
df.loc[2] = a
```

If need specify columns:

```
df.loc[2, ['volume','price','loc']] = a
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy- use loc:
new_df = df.loc[idx]
Passing an array to loc will select rows where index is in the array.